# replace the value based on condition with another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

how to change values based on condition another dataframe

i have a dataframe, but there are have a wrong location

```
df1=data.frame(code = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
                  Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","alpha","beta","charli"),
                  Location = c("A","B","C","B","C","A"))
```

the correct data in this dataframe

```
df2=data.frame(code = c("A1","A2","A1"),
                  Name = c("alpha","beta","charli"),
                  Location = c("C","B","A"))
```

so if Code and Name in df1=df2 the location is location in df2

my expected

```
df1=data.frame(code = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
                      Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","alpha","beta","charli"),
                      Location = c("C","B","A","B","B","A"))
```

Comment: do you mean you want to join the data.frames?

Comment: no, my expected like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do an update join. Here's one way in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

expected_df = data.frame(
  code = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2"),
  Name = c("alpha","beta","charli","alpha","beta","charli"),
  Location = c("C","B","A","B","B","A")
)

res = rows_update(df1, df2, by = c("code","Name"))

> res
  code   Name Location
1   A1  alpha        C
2   A1   beta        B
3   A1 charli        A
4   A2  alpha        B
5   A2   beta        B
6   A2 charli        A


identical(expected_df, res)
TRUE
```

Incase you're interested here's another way using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setDT(expected_df)

df1[df2, on = .(code, Name), Location := i.Location]

identical(df1, expected_df)
TRUE
```